# How to prepare data for all apps at once without loop for each app?

Tags: c#

I have one master list of 2 filters and this linked with one app,

```
var filterData = new List<FilterData>
            {
                new FilterData { Filter1 = "test1", Filter2 = "X", GoesToApp = "App1"},
                new FilterData { Filter1 = "test2", Filter2 = "X", GoesToApp = "App2"},
                new FilterData { Filter1 = "test2", Filter2 = "Y", GoesToApp = "App1"},
                new FilterData { Filter1 = "test3", Filter2 = "Y", GoesToApp = "App3"},
                new FilterData { Filter1 = "test4", Filter2 = "Y", GoesToApp = "App3"},
                new FilterData { Filter1 = "test1", Filter2 = "Z", GoesToApp = "App1"},
            };
```

Now I have one `Data` which contains above filters data as well,

```
var data = new Data
            {
                Id = 1,
                Filter2 = new List<string> { "X", "Y" },
                FilterValues = new List<FilterValue>
                {
                    new FilterValue {Filter1 = "test1", Value = "1"},
                    new FilterValue {Filter1 = "test2", Value = "2"},
                    new FilterValue {Filter1 = "test3", Value = "3"}
                }
            };
```

Here I need to filter `Data` with master list (above) on `Filter1` and `Filter2` and need to prepare data for each app (App1, App2 and so on).

With the code below I am able to **prepare data for only one app at a time**  (example, `App1`) and this gives me the desired data what I want for this app based on comparing filters,

```
var destData = new Data()
            {
                Id = 1,
                FilterValues = new List<FilterValue>()
            };

            var filter1DataForApp1 = filterData.Where(item =>
                    item.GoesToApp == "App1" && data.Filter2.Contains(item.Filter2))
                .Select(item => item.Filter1);


            foreach (var f1 in filter1DataForApp1)
            {
                destData.FilterValues.AddRange(data.FilterValues.Where(a => a.Filter1 == f1));
            }
```

For a single item in `Data` if I have 50 apps , then above code I need to run 50 times for each app, which I want to avoid. How to do this? Is this possible to generates all apps data in one query?

Here are different class structures,

```
public class FilterData
    {
        public string Filter1 { get; set; }
        public string Filter2 { get; set; }
        public string GoesToApp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Filter2 { get; set; }
        public List<FilterValue> FilterValues { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilterValue
    {
        public string Filter1 { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Expected output data for,

**App1** (only test1 and test2)

```
var app1Data = new Data
        {
            Id = 1,
            Filter2 = null,
            FilterValues = new List<FilterValue>
            {
                new FilterValue {Filter1 = "test1", Value = "1"},
                new FilterValue {Filter1 = "test2", Value = "2"}
            }
        };
```

**App2** (only test2)

```
var app1Data = new Data
        {
            Id = 1,
            Filter2 = null,
            FilterValues = new List<FilterValue>
            {
                new FilterValue {Filter1 = "test2", Value = "2"}
            }
        };
```

and so on...

I need one result something like something like `List<GoesToApp, List<datafor that app>>`

Comment: How is `Data` related to `GoesToApp`?

Comment: Can you show what your expected result is... not entirely clear. Does `Id = 1` refer to `App1`? SO are you looking for a collection of `destData` refering to your 3 apps?

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec, see my expected output for each app

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, `Data` has multiple `Filter1` which I need to split in distributed to right `AppToGoes`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
var result = filterData.GroupBy(x => x.GoesToApp).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => {        
        return new Data 
        {
            Id = 1,
            FilterValues = grp.Where(item => data.Filter2.Contains(item.Filter2)).SelectMany(item => data.FilterValues.Where(f => item.Filter1 == f.Filter1)).ToList() 
        };
    });
    
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    foreach(var fv in item.Value.FilterValues)
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{fv.Filter1}");
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xsomse

Comment: Thanks, but I need `GoesToApp` info as well.

Comment: something like `List<GoesToApp, List<datafor that app>>`

Comment: @user584018 ok, see update - just return a dictionary with the `GesToApp` as the key. It has the advantage that you can do `result["App1"]` for example

Comment: Super Sir. Excellent... Could you bit explain me the logic?

Comment: @user584018 the logic is exactly the same as your original, just first grouping by the `GoesToApp` so you can return a list of them

Comment: Ok, get it. Thanks and Appreciate!